# GETDATE() function in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date-formatting, getdate

When running the SQL query:

```
select GETDATE()
```

I get the below output:

```
2017-10-26 12:48:41.273
```

It displays the date and the time. But I want the output as

```
2017-10-26 00:00:00
```

How to get such a date format?

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112))
------------------------------------
SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GETDATE(),112))
```

Result :

```
2017-10-26 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 and later versions

**`SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'yyyy/dd/MM HH:mm:ss')`**

Result

for either of the above it would return:

```
10/16/2013 17:00:20
```